# Create a view to find the top 5 most expensive items in all Color Categories

Tags: sql-server

So I have to create a VIEW to find the top five most expensive product in each color category.

I know have to create a VIEW and I have figured out how to find the top 5 for each color group separately using, "SELECT TOP 5" at the start and "GROUP BY DESC" at the end of the query.

what I am struggling with is putting top five for all "Color"s in the same table.

below are my code and the error I get:

```
create view 
as  
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Black'
order by [ListPrice] desc   
    union ALL
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Blue'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union ALL
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Grey'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union ALL
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Multi'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union ALL
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Red'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union ALL
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Silver'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union ALL
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Silver/Black'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union all
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'White'
order by [ListPrice] desc
    union all
select top 5
[ProductID]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]

from [Production].[Product]
where [Color] = 'Yellow'
order by [ListPrice] desc

go
```

error code: (note I did not run the create view part yet just the query)

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 303
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 312
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 321
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 330
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 339
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 348
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 357
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 366
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
```

Comment: You get the error because you can have only one `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need union. Just select from your table and use window function like ROW_NUMBER to get the rank for the current color:

```
;with cte as (
select
    [ProductID]
    , [Color]
    , [ListPrice]
    , ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY [Color] ORDER BY [ListPrice] desc) as RowNo
from [Production].[Product]
)
select *
from cte
where RowNo <= 5
```

UPDATE: If there are products with the same price and you want to include all of them (i.e. for some color to return more than 5 rows), use [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of ROW_NUMBER.